# Kotlin - Reading in list of objects from JSON using GSON and Type Generics (Android)

Tags: json, generics, kotlin, gson

I have the a JSON file named `villagers.json` with a format that follows

```
[
  {
    "name": "Admiral",
    "iconFilename": "brd06.png",
    "houseFilename": "brd06_39_Admiral.png",
    "species": "Bird",
    "gender": "Male",
    "personality": "Cranky",
    "hobby": "Nature",
    "birthday": "01/27",
    "catchphrase": "aye aye",
    "favoriteSong": "Steep Hill",
    "filename": "brd06",
    "uid": "B3RyfNEqwGmcccRC3",
    "colors": [
      "Black",
      "Blue"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "Cool",
      "Cool"
    ]
  },
  { ... },
  etc.
]
```

The following snippet works to read in a list of `Villager` POJOs from the JSON file in Android assets.

```
// this works
fun getVillagersFromJSON(context: Context): List<Villager> {
    val jsonFileString = getJsonDataFromAsset(context, "villagers.json")
    return Gson().fromJson(jsonFileString, object : TypeToken<List<Villager>>() {}.type)
}
```

However, when attempting to use the following two functions to generify the type of the POJO, I get a `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to Villager` error.

```
    fun getVillagersFromJSON(context: Context): List<Villager> {
        val jsonFileString = getJsonDataFromAsset(context, "villagers.json")
        jsonFileString?.let { return fromJson(it) }
        return ArrayList()
    }

    // this use of type generics does NOT work
    private inline fun <reified T> fromJson(json: String): List<T> {
        return Gson().fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.type)
    }
```

**What is the correct way to use Kotlin, Gson, and type generics to read in a list of POJOs from a JSON file?**

Comment: can you show json content

Answer (score 0):

The closest I was able to get to using generics was the following, although I'm still seeking a better solution where I don't need to explicitly specify all the type possibilities.

```
    fun getVillagersFromJSON(context: Context): List<Villager> {
         val jsonFileString = getJsonDataFromAsset(context, "villagers.json")
         jsonFileString?.let { return fromJson(it, Villager::class) }
         return ArrayList<Villager>()
    }

    private inline fun <reified T : Any> fromJson(json: String, clazz: KClass<T>): List<T> {
        return when (clazz) {
            Villager::class -> Gson().fromJson(
                json,object : TypeToken<List<Villager>>() {}.type
            ) as List<T>
            // put other cases here
            else -> ArrayList()
        }
    }
```